# What do `ns` and `us` stand for in `timeit` result?

Tags: python, timeit

I was trying to compare performance of two statements with `timeit`, and the results are something like:

```
 100 loops, best of 3: 100 ns per loop
 100 loops, best of 3: 1.96 us per loop
```

But I don't know what these `ns` and `us` stands for, so I don't know which one is faster.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

*ns* stands for nanoseconds. *n* is the regular [SI prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) meaning 10<sup>-9</sup>. *us* means microseconds.  In SI that would be *µs* (10<sup>-6</sup> seconds) - the *u* is used because there's not a *µ* in ASCII, but it does look pretty similar.  In your case, that means you're comparing 100×10<sup>-9</sup> seconds against 1.96×10<sup>-6</sup> seconds - the former is almost 20× faster.

Answer (score 10):

Nanoseconds and microseconds... 10<sup>-9</sup> and 10<sup>-6</sup> respectively.